# 8.7 typoscript select join subqueries not working

Tags: select, join, subquery, typoscript, typo3-8.x

why this typo3 8.7 typoscript-parser kills my join subqueries?

```
join = (SELECT * FROM tt_content Join (SELECT sys_language_uid FROM `tt_content` WHERE (pid=119)AND
```

thats the result (..starts after " SELECT * FROM 'tt_content' INNER JOIN ")

```
'SELECT * FROM `tt_content` INNER JOIN `(SELECT` * ON tt_content Join (SELECT sys_language_uid FROM `tt_content` WHERE (pid=119)AND
```

> https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84949

---

anybody have another solutuion to get page-content over uid in the current language (if empty get from default language)